# @Query Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I need to replace this code from pgAdmin4:

`DELETE from order_entity where (LOCALTIMESTAMP - local_date_time > '00:10:00')`

to @Query Spring boot like:

`@Query(" DELETE from OrderEntity o where (current_timestamp - o.localDateTime < '00:10:00')")`

But i have and issue near where: `'(', <expression>, FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '('`

Help please.

Comment: You don't need `(`. Try without it

Comment: then pop out `<expression>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected, got '-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA according to the specification does not offer any method to subtract timestamps and for this reason the `-` operator is not recognized for that use that you have here with timestamps. So this is why you receive this error.

There are 3 type of solutions here:

- Make the calculation of `current_timestamp - o.localDateTime` in java and then pass the calculated value in the query. Then JPA would not have any issue with this query. For example `where calc_diff < '00:10:00'`.
- Use a native query where your DB vendor may support this action, with some specific function offered.
- 1. If you use, Eclipse Link as JPA implementation, take advantage of the [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/toplink/jpa-extensions-reference/jpql.htm#func) method inside `JPQL` language with which you can call inside a JPA query specific functions that exist for your Database vendor.
  2. If you use Hibernate as JPA implementation, take advantage of the [SQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-function-sql) method inside `JQPL` language with which you can call inside a JPA query specific functions that exist for your Database vendor.

  The above 2 methods for Eclipse Link/ Hibernate would allow you to have a `JPQL` query mixed with some native query for the part that is not supported from JPA, to subtract timestamps.

Comment: still have an issue: `')' or <expression> expected, got '-'` next to `(current_timestamp - o.localDateTime)` to minus sign